# how to write plist that contains array of dictionary

Tags: objective-c, plist

I'm a new developer for the iPhone. I have a plist file (named "Favorites") in main bundle.

I need to write the data with the following structure, for 20 dictionary items.
how would I write?

```
<array>
<dict>
    <key>PubDate</key>
    <date>2011-08-12T23:15:12Z</date>
    <key>ImageName</key>
    <string>abc.png</string>
    <key>Title</key>
    <string>ABCDEF</string>
    <key>Description</key>
    <string>Suggestions?</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>PubDate</key>
    <date>2011-08-12T23:15:12Z</date>
    <key>ImageName</key>
    <string>abc.png</string>
    <key>Title</key>
    <string>ABCDEF</string>
    <key>Description</key>
    <string>Suggestions?</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>PubDate</key>
    <date>2011-08-12T23:15:12Z</date>
    <key>ImageName</key>
    <string>abc.png</string>
    <key>Title</key>
    <string>ABCDEF</string>
    <key>Description</key>
    <string>Suggestions?</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "How to write"?

Answer (score 0):

Well don't expect people to write out all the code for you, but this is probably close to what you're looking for.

```
//Put this where you want to write the data. add is the filename you want to save under
    [info writeToFile:[self saveFilePath:add] atomically:YES];

//Put this somewhere in your class
- (NSString*) saveFilePath: (NSString *) add
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filename = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:add];
    return filename;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will  Suggest you to make a Java type dictionary bcoz a dictionary is immutable so you create it once and you can't add or remove objects. For a Java like dictionary you need to use NSMutableDictionary....